# How to pipe a new command after ffmpeg background process completes?

Tags: php, video, process, background, ffmpeg

This is my `ffmpeg` process:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i source.avi dest.mp4 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Now, I wish to execute a PHP file after the conversion is complete. Logically, this is what I have:

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i source.avi dest.mp4 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; php proceed.php &
```

This doesn't work though, since then PHP will hold up the process to wait till the `ffmpeg` conversion is complete. What I want is basically to call proceed.php after the conversion completes, both of which are done in the background.

If anyone can provide the Windows server solution, that will be awesome too.

Comment: Windows server solution? Your paths are not Windows paths?

Comment: Rather than `;` use `&&`, so that `proceed.php` is called only if `ffmpeg` succeeds. Better yet, use something like Gearman to distribute the tasks into queues.

Comment: @Lee Yeah I'm requesting for both linux and windows solutions if possible.

Comment: @halfer using && or ; will result in the same thing in this case, in terms of what I'm asking for in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Write an external (bash/php) script that executes both the ffmpeg and php process, and tack `&` after that.

For windows, please open a new question on SO.

Comment: Wow this sounds like an awesome idea! It'll probably work for windows too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To add on to what Evert had posted, here is an example of what I use for my FFMPEG bash script... it's far from done (it doesn't alert if the program crashes, for instance) but it's somewhere to start:

```
#!/bin/sh

## Set our paths
FFMPEG_PATH=/usr/local/bin
SITE_PATH=path_to_file
VIDEO_PATH=$SITE_PATH/public_html/videos

## Make sure we have permissions to do this stuff
chown -R wwwrun:www $VIDEO_PATH/$2
chmod -R 765 $VIDEO_PATH/$2

## Set the options for mp4 compression
options="-vcodec libx264 -b 512k -ar 22050 -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 \
       -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 \
       -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 \
       -flags2 +bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8 -coder 1 -me_range 16 \
       -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10\
       -qmax 51 -qdiff 4"

## Start the conversion.
$FFMPEG_PATH/ffmpeg -y -i $VIDEO_PATH/$2/original/$1 -an -pass 1 -threads 2 $options $VIDEO_PATH/$2/$2.mp4 2> $VIDEO_PATH/$2/pass_one.log
$FFMPEG_PATH/ffmpeg -y -i $VIDEO_PATH/$2/original/$1 -acodec libfaac -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 $options $VIDEO_PATH/$2/$2.mp4 2> $VIDEO_PATH/$2/pass_two.log

## Create the thumbnail for the video
. $SITE_PATH/bin/create_thumbnail $2 00:00:15 2> $VIDEO_PATH/$2/generate_thumbnails.log

## Clean up the log files that were created
## find /log_path/ -name *log* -exec rm {} \;

## Update datbase and send email that we're done here.
php $SITE_PATH/public_html/admin/includes/video_status.php converting_finished $2
```

And this all gets called from a PHP file that does (along with some other code):

```
proc_close(proc_open(server_path.'/bin/convert_video_mp4 '.mysql_result($next_video, 0, "uid").'.'.mysql_result($next_video, 0, "original_ext").' '.mysql_result($next_video, 0, "uid").' &', array(), $foo));
```

PS - I know mysql extension are on their way out, I haven't been using or updating this code in a while, so please update to your specifications

Comment: Why are you not using the [x264 encoding presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) instead of declaring a legion of options?

Comment: Because when I first wrote this (about 4 years ago) I didn't know much about what encoding settings to use and found those options on a site. It gave pretty good quality at decent file sizes. I haven't actually revisited this code in a long time, but plan on doing so soon and I was going to open those options up into a preference in the web interface so a user could tweak or choose from some presets. But thanks for the link, when I go to rewrite this will be really nice to have.